# How to set set Screen type with python

Tags: python

Found nothing in Python API to set Screen type (other than `"Default"`).

Is it possible?

My need is to set it programmatically, with python script !

Answer (score 6):

`bpy.context.screen` is a shorthand, but read-only.

You can set a screen via the Window object, which actually holds the screen reference:

```
bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['UV Editing']
```

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.Window.html#bpy.types.Window.screen

There's also an operator to change screen by a number, relative to the currently active screen:

```
bpy.ops.screen.screen_set(delta=1) # select screen after current from list
```

This is what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> trigger (with a delta of -1 or 1 respectively).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bpy.context.window.screen`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.window) = [`bpy.data.screens['screen_name']`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.screens). To see all your screen types, run:

```
for screen in bpy.data.screens:
    print(screen.name)
```